# SVG not displayed when hosted

Tags: svg, browser

i hosted a website on localhost - there is everything fine. but when i upload it to my hoster the svg is not displayed - whether if i load the page nor if i go to the svg (which is seperatet in a .php file) directly.

The opening lines of my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 620 620" width="auto" height="100%"><path d=" M 284 11.7 C 239.8 16.1 197.2 29.5 160.2 50.7 C 125.5...
```

Is there any mistake? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: my guess would be that you're not serving the file with the correct mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the following part fixed it. I do not have an explanation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```